# Relation between pointwise convergence and convergence in measure.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> Let $f_{n} \rightarrow f$ almost everywhere with $f$ integrable. Show that $\int |f_{n}-f|\rightarrow 0$ if and only if $\int |f_{n}|\rightarrow \int |f|$. Does this result still hold if we assume $f_{n} \rightarrow f$ in measure instead of pointwise?

For the first question $(\Rightarrow)$ it follows from the triangular inequality.   As for $(\Leftarrow)$ in order to use Vitali theorem, I want to use the fact that if $\left\{f_{n}\right\}$ is $L^{p}$ bounded $(p\geq 1)$, then it would be uniformly integrable. But I don't know how to prove it. I don't know how to construct a counterexample for the second question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first part of your question, define
$$ h_n=|f|+|f_n|-|f-f_n| $$
Then $h_n\geq 0$ for all $n$, so we can apply Fatou's lemma to obtain
$$2\int |f|=\int \liminf_{n\to\infty}h_n\leq \liminf_{n\to\infty}\int h_n=2\int|f|-\limsup_{n\to\infty}\int|f-f_n|$$
and since $\int|f|$ is finite this shows that 
$$\limsup_{n\to\infty}\int |f-f_n|=0 $$

For the second part, if $f_n\to f$ in measure then $h_n\to 2|f|$ in measure. Choose a subsequence $\{h_{n_k}\}$ such that
$$ \lim_{k\to\infty}\int h_{n_k}=\liminf_{n\to\infty}\int h_n $$
then since $h_{n_k}\to 2|f|$ in measure, there is a further subsequence such that $h_{n_{k_j}}\to 2|f|$ almost everywhere. Therefore by Fatou's lemma
$$ 2\int |f|\leq \lim_{j\to\infty}\int h_{n_{k_j}}=\liminf_{n\to\infty}\int h_n $$
and now the proof proceeds as in the first case.

Comment: It's a very beautiful proof.Just one more question,how can guarantee that we can find  a subsequence $\{h_{n_k}\}$ such that $$ \lim_{k\to\infty}\int h_{n_k}=\liminf_{n\to\infty}\int h_n $$

Comment: Well $\{\int h_n\}$ is a sequence of real numbers, and for any sequence of real numbers there is a subsequence which converges to the liminf.